# Create a multicolor selectbox on Symfony2

Tags: php, css, symfony, drop-down-menu

I try to create the following field :

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="1">a</option>
    <option value="2">b</option>
    <option value="3" style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">c *</option>
    <option value="4">d</option>
    <option value="5">e</option>
</select>
```

This creates a 2-color selectbox :

[image]

But in Symfony2, I do not know how to apply a class to a single option.

If in my view I do :

```
{{
    form_widget(myForm.test, {
        'attr': {
            'class': 'red',
        }
    }) 
}}
```

Or if in my form I do :

```
    $builder->add('test', 'choice', array(
            'required' => true,
            'choices' => array('a', 'b', 'c *', 'd', 'e'),
            'attr' => array('class' => 'red'),
    ));
```

The attribute is stored into the `<select>` tag and apply to the whole selectable values.

## Edit

I solved the problem using jQuery :

1) in my view I put :

```
{{
    form_widget(myForm.test, {
        'attr': {
            'class': 'starred-select',
        }
    }) 
}}
```

2) in my javascripts, I put :

```
    $('.starred-select option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text().substr(-2) == ' *') {
            $(this).addClass('red');
        }
    });
```

Of course, my values can't finish by a star.

**How can I apply a class to an `<option>` tag in Symfony2 ?**

Comment: Just so you're aware, not all rendering engines support styling of option elements. Webkit doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to override the way your widget choice field is rendered.

[Form Theming](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming) allows you to customize every part of your form. Even [base form blocks](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#referencing-base-form-blocks-twig-specific) can be overriden.

The best method to do this is to copy the default block from [form_div_layout.html.twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.1/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig)
 (In your case you've to override the `widget_choice_options` block)

You can also customize your block at [different levels](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-theming-in-twig) of your application. Take a deeper look at [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#referencing-base-form-blocks-twig-specific), it includes fully explained examples.

Comment: Looks good but a bit hmmm, how to say, a hard job just to add attributes to an `<option>`...

Comment: Not that hard, the documentation contains many use cases and examples. You've just to override one part (depending on your needs). inheritance can also help you keep your code clear and simple.